# obtain an authorization token of an endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, api, token

I need to obtain an authorization token of an endpoint that is in an api1, passing a user and password as a parameter, this endpoint would call it from an api2 in spring boot, could someone help me ??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

you can just provide a RestController endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getToken", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String json)
```

In this example you can pass a JSON with username/password and any other extra attributes you might need. You can replace the string above with a DTO if you find easier. Another option is to pass the 2 parameters

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getToken", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password)
```